# Failure to read XML Schema Document

Tags: xml, netbeans, xsd

I am new to XML Schema, and currently following classes into it. The following question follows from one of the assignments thereof. The assignment was to set up an XML Schema document for one of the XML Documents we had to make before. The XML Document looks like this:

```
<? xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<CPBISchema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns="http://ds.arch.tue.nl/7m900/assignment/cpbischema" 
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://ds.arch.tue.nl/7m900/assignment/cpbischema
                            Assignment 2.2a 7M900 NAM van de Ven.xsd">

<person id="p1">
    <login>N.Johnston</login>
    <password>johnston1508</password>
    <name>Nicholas F. Johnston</name>
    <address>199, 51st Street</address>
    <city>New Orleans</city>
    <email>n.johnston@cpbi.com</email>
    <Ref_person.requirements requirements="r2" />
    <Ref_person.collective />
</person>
<!-- etc. -->

<collective id="c1">
    <homepage href="http://www.bam.nl/" />
    <description>Koninklijke BAM groep nv</description>
    <active>yes</active>
    <Ref_collective.person person="p1"/>
    <Ref_collective.person_ManagedBy person="p2"/>
    <Ref_collective.requirements requirements="r1"/>
</collective> 
<!-- etc. -->
</CPBISchema>
```

With the following XML Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
        targetNamespace="http://ds.arch.tue.nl/7m900/assignment/cpbischema"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
            schemaLocation="xlink.xsd"/>
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" 
            schemaLocation="xml.xsd"/>

<xsd:complexType name="CPBISchema"> 
    <xsd:sequence> 
        <xsd:element name="person" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" /> 
        <xsd:element name="collective" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" /> 
        <xsd:element name="requirements" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" /> 
        <xsd:element name="spacerequirements" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" /> 
        <xsd:element name="dwelling" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" /> 
        <xsd:element name="space" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" /> 
    </xsd:sequence> 
</xsd:complexType> 
<xsd:element name="CPBISchema" type="CPBISchema" />

<xsd:complexType name="Person"> 
    <xsd:sequence> 
        <xsd:element name="login" type="xsd:string" /> 
        <xsd:element name="password">
            <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                    <xsd:pattern value="[a-z]+/d{4}" />
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" /> 
        <xsd:element name="address" type="xsd:string" /> 
        <xsd:element name="city" type="xsd:string" /> 
        <xsd:element name="email" type="xsd:string" /> 
        <xsd:element name="Ref_person.requirements">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:attribute name="requirements" type="xsd:IDREF" use="required" />
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="Ref_person.collective" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:attribute name="collective" type="xsd:IDREF" use="optional" />
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence> 
    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:ID" use="required" />
</xsd:complexType> 
<xsd:element name="person" type="Person" />

<xsd:complexType name="Collective">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="homepage">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:attributeGroup ref="xlink:simpleLink" />
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="description" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="active" type="xsd:boolean" />
        <xsd:element name="Ref_collective.person" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:attribute name="person" type="xsd:IDREF" use="optional" />
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="Ref_collective.person_ManagedBy">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:attribute name="person" type="xsd:IDREF" use="required" />
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="Ref_collective.requirements">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:attribute name="requirements" type="xsd:IDREF" use="required" />
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:ID" use="required" />
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="collective" type="Collective" />
</xsd:schema>
```

When validating the XML Document for the XML Schema - as was the assignment - NetBeans (which is the program I use) gave the following error message: 
schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'Assignment', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not .

My guess is that I'm not declaring the schema document the right way, but where the mistake lies exactly I do not know. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct XSD is ..

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
        targetNamespace="http://ds.arch.tue.nl/7m900/assignment/cpbischema"
        xmlns="http://ds.arch.tue.nl/7m900/assignment/cpbischema"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">
```

The correct XML is ..

```
<CPBISchema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns="http://ds.arch.tue.nl/7m900/assignment/cpbischema" 
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://ds.arch.tue.nl/7m900/assignment/cpbischema
                            Assignment2.2a7M900NAMvandeVen.xsd 
                            http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink xlink.xsd">
```

- You must rename the XSD `Assignment 2.2a 7M900 NAM van de Ven.xsd` in `Assignment2.2a7M900NAMvandeVen.xsd` because the spaces are problem when use `schemaLocation`.
- You must add on the schemaLocation `xlink.xsd` declaration.

[See this reference to use of schemaLocation](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_schema.asp)

#### Referencing a Schema in an XML Document

> This attribute has two values, separated by a space. The first value
>   is the namespace to use. The second value is the location of the XML
>   schema to use for that namespace:
>
> xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com note.xsd"